# Passing additional value to Controller method - Razor/MVC 5

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

Hello I am having some trouble figuring out how to pass an additional value to my Controller's Delete method.

I have a form with a Delete button (auto-generated MVC).

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-actions no-color">
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" />
        <button onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "Admin")';return false;" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" style="font-size:10px">Admin</button>
    </div>
}
```

But I want to send along an additional value, this value would be the result of `getCookie("username");`

I have tried making another input and calling it.

```
<input type="text" name="userid" value="getCookie('username')"  />
```

The problem is that this always shows "null" within my Controller method.

The method is

```
    // GET: /Admin/Delete/5
    public ActionResult Delete(int? id, string userid)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        User user = db.Users.Find(id);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(user);
    }
```

and

```
// POST: /Admin/Delete/5
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id, string userid)
{
    User user = db.Users.Find(id);
    db.Users.Remove(user);
    db.SaveChanges();
    var time = new DateTime();
    string text = time + ": User " + user.name + " was deleted.";
    System.IO.File.AppendAllText(pathway, text + Environment.NewLine);
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

All I want is to have the value of `getCookie('username');` passed on to a method as `userID`.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: The value of parameter id will always be null because you do not have an input with `name="id"`

Comment: @StephenMuecke `id` isn't the issue, for some reason MVC always know the `id` and has a value for it. I assume it is due to some auto-generated magic that was built in during the Controller's creation. I am trying to pass `userID` which should be `getCookie("username")`'s value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you would want to do is have getcookie() set the value (using jQuery, or whatever) of the userId  instead of returning it. You'd need to call this on page load. That would put the value in the DOM/form, so it posts to your controller action.

That said, can't you just access the cookies in your action from the Request object?

Comment: I tried looking around about calling my Cookie within the ActionResult (if that's what you mean) but from what I reading it isn't a clean way to do it. I will trying storing it upon load. I just worry that what if userA loads the page, then waits a minut, then userB loads the page. If userA then click's submit, will it have userA's value or userB's value?

Comment: See what the value of this is if you put it in your Controller Action/Method...

string s = Request.Cookies["username"];

Comment: it returns `"System.Web.HttpCookie"` in debug.

Comment: Sorry... Lack of compiler... I meant: string s = Request.Cookies["username"].Value;

Comment: Cookies are unique to the user. User A would always get User A's value.

Comment: Is that not the desired effect? If not, you are right. Cookies are not the way to solve this problem.